# How to remove VirtualBox from Ubuntu permanently?

Tags: apt, virtualbox, software-uninstall

I need help removing VirtualBox from my computer.

I've already tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtual-box-*
sudo apt-get purge virtual-box-*
```

it just said it was selecting some stuff and then it said it didn't remove them and commented:

```
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic but it is not going to be installed 
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-79-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic (= 4.4.0-79.100) but it is not going to be installed 
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-87-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic (= 4.4.0-87.110) but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unmet dependencies.  
Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```